# ¿Cómo actualizar los datos de una página sin consumir recursos del Host?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Estoy realizando un sistema de alertas o notificaciones que debe ir actualizándose automáticamente de tal modo que apenas se asigne un seguimiento al usuario logueado, la alerta debe mostrársele de inmediato. Es algo tipo notificación de Facebook que apenas un usuario tiene una solicitud o mensaje, éstas se les notifica de inmediato.

Yo lo hice con JQuery Ajax, PHP y MySQL, desde el JQuery se hace la solicitud por Ajax cada 5 segundos al archivo PHP donde se consulta la información por MySQL, esto funciona y efectivamente actualiza automáticamente y va mostrando las notificaciones a medida que se va asignando el seguimiento al usuario logueado.

> **El problema :** Está en que son 20 usuarios conectados y esos 20 están haciendo peticiones cada 5 segundos a la base de datos, lo que me satura el límite de procesos de entrada del Host de la página web, el recurso se muestra en el Cpanel como Entry Processes, en la imagen de abajo dejo el recurso, está bajo por que desactive el sistema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **La consulta :** ¿Existe alguna otra forma de realizar este sistema sin llevar los recursos del Host al límite?

*Nota: No veo necesario colocar el código de cómo lo estoy haciendo por que está funcionando y mi consulta es si hay alguna manera de cumplir con el requerimiento haciéndolo de un modo diferente, pero si es necesario colocar el código lo pondría con gusto.*

Comment: Si quieres una opcion es utilziar EventSource(https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventSource)

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que estés intentando realizar y de las tecnologías que estés usando en cliente y servidor, podrías plantearte muchas opciones: notificaciones Push,  AJAX, EventSource, sockets... lo cual podría hacer la pregunta algo amplia y basada en opiniones.

Comment: No está basada en opiniones, si existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo es responder cómo, no estoy preguntando como lo harían, estoy preguntando cómo hacerlo de otro modo existente que yo no conozca.

Comment: @HenryParra ¿Existe alguna otra forma de realizarlo? Sí. ¿Cuál es esa forma? Pues hay bastantes, y para cada una de ellas hay plugins, bibliotecas y hasta frameworks creados que podrías usar. ¿Es alguno mejor que los demás? No, eso dependerá de la situación y la experiencia del programador. Por eso digo que no es una pregunta concreta, sino más bien subjetiva. Podrías acabar con muchas respuestas todas igualmente válidas y sujetas a la opinión del programador.

Comment: No entiendo por que dan puntuación negativa si estoy consultando otra manera que yo desconozca de hacer lo que requiero, esta pregunta no está basada en opiniones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizar Jquery para realizar un monitoreo o consulta automática a tu base es muy mala idea, como te ocurre, vas a saturar los recursos.

Utiliza firebase en tu web para estas tareas, es muy simple de utilizar, visita su [DOCUMENTACION](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?authuser=0)

Puedes utilizar su realtime database para crear nodos por cada usuario y monitorear los movimientos que allí se registren, de igual manera hay un sdk que puedes integrar a php para la comunicación con la database.

[SDK PHP FIREBASE](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html)

luego simplemente crea el observador de los nodos y crear las alertas que creas conveniente sin saturar tu sistema:

```
    var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('NODOAMONITOREAR/' + postId);
//Monitorea si se agregan elementos al nodo    
commentsRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
      //AQUI LO QUE VALLAS A HACER
    });

//Monitorea si se modifica algo en el nodo
    commentsRef.on('child_changed', function(data) {
      //AQUI LO QUE VALLAS A HACER
    });

//Monitorea las eliminaciones de datos enel nodo
    commentsRef.on('child_removed', function(data) {
      //AQUI LOQUE VALLAS A HACER
    });
```

De esa manera puedes crearte un sistema de alertas en tiempo real sin problemas, un chat, incluso enviar notificaciones push a aplicaciones mobiles android e ios sin que tu sistema colapse o siquiera se entere, ya que es firebase el encargado del trabajo.

Saludos espero haberte orientado.